# Is there a way to test markers on MapView using DETOX in a react-native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, automation, detox

I have a react native app that includes MapView component where we are rendering the markers. Using detox, I want to test the visibility of those markers and also if they can be tapped or not. I have applied the testID using the index function which will make it unique, but I am still not able to check the visibility of the markers. Is there any other way.
Please help!!

[image]

Environment :

- Detox: 18.7.0
- React Native: 0.63.3
- Node: 14.16.0
- Device: Pixel_API_23x86(android) OR iPhone 11 Pro(iOS)
- OS: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- Test-runner: jest-circus

Comment: I'm guessing that the markers are not react native components, are they? If so, I think you may find Detox' [element screenshots API](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Screenshots.md#element-level-screenshots) useful. It would allow you to take a snapshot of the map-view (in a very deterministic test case) and then compare it with a preinstalled result. Follow the link for the complete info.